# Selenium - fill forms on many websites

Tags: java, selenium

I'm creating my script in Selenium which is filling form on website. Works very well.
But I have a few websites, every form is different so I have 3 scripts which I have to open separately. Is it possible to make it automate in one script?

Below two files I have to open separately now:

```
package com.myform.tests.copy;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class FillMyForm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.example2.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailfield")).sendKeys("test@example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("surnamefield")).sendKeys("John");
        driver.findElement(By.id("phonefield")).sendKeys("123123123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("agreefield")).click();            
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitfield")).click();   
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("result")).getText());      
    }
}


package com.myform.tests.copy.copy;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class FillMyForm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.example.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("test@example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("surname")).sendKeys("John");
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys("123123123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("agree")).click();         
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();    
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("bd")).getText());      
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the scripts

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: why don't you use  [TestNg Data Provider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm very newbie in Selenium - now, just able to copy/paste and modify

Comment: Ok in that case I would suggest you to go and check the above link and try to implement the same. If there are any issues then you can come back with your query.

Comment: Firstly, why are you using `Thread.sleep`? AFAIK Selenium waits for a page to load before starting to find elements. And if the element is loaded after loading, then you should use [**Wait**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/4435/wait#t=201608040936058229239) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the execution is the same for every form, you might want to create a template for the execution paths. Once you have the template, you can pass your code to execute based on the template.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to say using https://github.com/codezombies/easytest

```
public static class PageActions {
    ActionableTemplate fillUpFormTemplate;
    ActionableTemplate afterFormSubmitTemplate;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    PageActions action1 = new PageActions();
    action1.fillUpFormTemplate = element -> {
        element.typeText("#emailfield", "test@example.com");
        element.typeText("#surnamefield", "John");
        element.typeText("#phonefield", "123123123");
        element.click("#agreefield");            
        element.click("#submitfield");     
    };
    action1.afterFormSubmitTemplate = element -> {
      System.out.println(element.get("#result"));  
    };

    PageActions action2 = new PageActions();
    action2.fillUpFormTemplate = element -> {
        element.typeText("#email", "test@example.com");
        element.typeText("#surname", "John");
        element.typeText("#phone", "123123123");
        element.click("#agree");            
        element.click("#submit");     
    };
    action2.afterFormSubmitTemplate = element -> {
        System.out.println(element.get("#bd"));  
    };

    final Map<String, PageActions> actions = new HashMap<>();
    actions.put("http://wwww.example1.com", action1);
    actions.put("http://wwww.example2.com", action2);

    for (Map.Entry<String, PageActions> entry : actions.entrySet()) {

        // execution template starts here
        EasyTestOptions options = new EasyTestOptions();
        options.addActionTemplate("fillUpForm", entry.getValue().fillUpFormTemplate);
        options.addActionTemplate("afterSubmit", entry.getValue().afterFormSubmitTemplate);

        try(EasyTest easy = new EasyTest(DriverType.FIREFOX)) {

            easy.start(entry.getKey());

            easy.newPage(page -> {
               page.executeTemplate("fillUpForm"); 
            });

            easy.newPage(page -> {
               page.executeTemplate("afterSubmit"); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```